# SSIS - EXCEL Destination is going blank

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package which exports the data from several tables and exports it to the Excel destination(Each table on different sheets and each in different Dataflow task).Among the five tables two tables are not going to excel destination even though the logging in SSIS is showing as n number of rows have been exported.

I have tried the following,

1.Changed the 64 bit run time to false,

2.Set delay validation as true,

3.Tried changing the number of data records on the error tables,

4.Tried exporting the data straight from database using export wizard, still issue.

This problem is occurring only for those two tables and they each having around 15 columns whereas the remaining tables are coming correctly.Can someone suggest if you have any similar problem and if so how to resolve this?

Comment: Try adding a DataViewer and check if records are showing up in the DataViewer.

Comment: the different Data Flow Task run in parallel or they are linked using Precedence constraints?